# two sonicwalls appliances, mail server and nat

Tags: sonicwall

I've two sonicwall connecting two places through VPN.

In place A I've a Mail Server. I need that this mail server can be accessed through internet connection of place B. Here's an schema:

INTERNET A ________________________    INTERNET B   <--- Users must be connect to MAIL SERVER from here

PLACE A-----------VPN-----------PLACE B

MAIL SERVER

I've tryed to add NAT Policies in both sonicwalls, configured some firewall rules... But I can't connect to MAIL SERVER through public IP of INTERNET B.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want users from the place B to access the mail server through **VPN** or through their **WAN connection**?

If it is through **VPN**, you should be able to with the **private IP** address and the **local ports** of the email server.

EMAIL SERVER LOCAL PORTS <--- EMAIL SERVER LOCAL IP <--- SONICWALL A <--- VPN <--- SONICWALL B <--- USER

If you want them to access it through their **WAN connection** and that they are connecting to the email server using a **public IP** address, then you should create two things: One **Firewall rule** and one **NAT rule**.

EMAIL SERVER LOCAL PORTS <--- EMAIL SERVER LOCAL IP <--- SONICWALL A PUBLIC PORTS <--- SONICWALL A PUBLIC IP ADDRESS <--- ISP A <--- INTERNET <--- ISP B <--- SONICWALL B <--- USERS

For the firewall rule, you will need to configure it like so:
**From Zone**: WAN
**To Zone:** LAN
**Service**: "The service object/group that contains all the ports through which the users will be accessing your mail server"
**Source**: Any
**Destination**: WAN Interface IP

Then you will need to add the following **NAT policy**:
**Original Source**: Any
**Translated Source**: Original
**Original Destination**: WAN Primary IP
**Translated Destination**: "The address Object that contains the LAN IP address of your Email Server"
**Original Service**: "The service object/group that contains all the ports through which the users will be accessing your mail server"
**Translated Service**: "If the ports of the email server are the same as the one of the original service, select Original, otherwise, select the service object/group that contains all the ports of the local email server."

These are the basic configuration of the rules and you can customize the parameters on the other tabs.

Please note that those rules will also allow users to connect from home or from anywhere else. If you want only the SITE B to access your Email server through their Internet connection, you should change the "Source" of the Firewall rule and the "Original Source" field for the address object that contains the public IP of the SITE B.